# Applying/earning/validating leave

Tags: writing

When someone attends an event, he will be awarded some additional leave subject to his boss's approval. Therefore, he will need to submit a leave application to his boss for approval.

Should I call this (action 1) *apply leave*, *submit leave*, *apply new leave* or something else?

Note that if we use *apply leave* or *submit leave*, we will have another problem as follows. If that someone wants to *use* the leave that his boss had approved for action 1, he will need to submit this further application to his boss for approval.

Then, should I call this (action 2) *apply leave* (not again?), *submit leave* (not again?) or something else?

Comment: I don't understand the second action. If someone has already applied for leave why would they need to apply again in order to *use* it?

Comment: @Waggers, please read carefully. The first action is when you "earn" a leave. The second action is when you "spend" a leave. I have a headache on how to properly define them.

Comment: I *did* read carefully but that meaning wasn't clear. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: This question may be better suited for UX.SE (but I think it's ok here)

Comment: @Waggers. Thanks for editing my question - imo, your version is better than my versions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user is receiving a "leave credit" for attending the event. When they need to take time off, they're requesting leave. I'd use:

1. Apply for Leave Credit
2. Request Leave

I think most English speakers will understand this.

Comment: Marked as answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the first action I would use something like:

- Apply for additional leave
- Amend leave entitlement
- Submit change request
- Update available leave

And for the second, something like:

- Submit leave application
- Request leave
- Book leave

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are asking for suggestions for names of two actions or forms, on the one hand a granting or obtaining of credits toward future leave, and on the other application for specific leave dates.

Phrases for case 1:

- Add to accrued leave
- Record credit for future leave
- Update accrued leave credits
- Update leave credits
- Submit leave credits

Phrases for case 2:

- Approve leave dates
- Approve leave schedule
- Apply to take a leave
- Apply for leave
- Set leave dates