# Two single word (if possible) each to describe two different Leave types

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

There are two scenario as follows:

1. Person who receive "Leave Credit" when attending some events.
2. Person who "Request Leave" when they want to take time off.

I was thinking of using "Credit" to replace "Leave Credit" and "Request" to replace "Request Leave but to the user, they find it quite "ambiguous". Some more, they want single word instead of two words to describe the type of leave they are applying.

So, may I know if there are single word each to replace "Leave Credit" and "Request Leave"?

**Update**

Let me rephrase my question:

I am looking for a single word alternative to replace the following words:

- Leave Credit
- Request Leave

**Update**

Insert the table below describe my questions further.

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Name               |   Leave Type           |        From    |       To      |  
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Jack               |   Leave Credit         |  2010 06 06    | 2010 06 07    |
| Jill               |   Request Leave        |  2010 07 16    | 2010 07 17    |
| John               |   Leave Credit         |  2010 08 20    | 2010 08 21    |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Based on Hugo, it is difficult to use single word like 'Credit' or 'Request' (as shown in the table below) as it will increase confusion.

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Name               |   Leave Type           |        From    |       To      |  
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Jack               |   Credit               |  2010 06 06    | 2010 06 07    |
| Jill               |   Request              |  2010 07 16    | 2010 07 17    |
| John               |   Credit               |  2010 08 20    | 2010 08 21    |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: I don't understand this question. Do you mean that the employer wishes to record absence from work separately as either "attending work-related events" or "for personal reasons"?

Comment: Something like that. The employer would like to see statistics such as the number of "Leave Credits" and "Request Leave" but as you know, statistics don't have "long wording", so the user want to have "short wording" - preferably single word to describe both "Leave Credits" and "Request Leave". Kind of hard to find single word, right?

Comment: Your "something like that" leaves me none the wiser as to what these two different types of leave actually are. You could just call them "Type A" and "Type B". If my guess about "attending work-related events" is actually correct, you could go for **vocational** and **personal**.

Comment: Maybe I will rephrase it in this way - The employer does not care if the leave is to attend work-related events or personal reasons. The employer want to know if there is a single word for "Leave Credit". The employer also want to know if there is a single word for "Request Leave". The employer will put this two word on a radio box of a form for the employee to tick. After each month, the employer will calculate the number of ticks for each radio box.

Comment: If rephrase as Type A and Type B, then Type A is "Leave Credit". Type B is "Request Leave". However, the employer want a single word for each Type. Therefore Type A cannot be called "Leave Credit", it should be called "?" (a single word). Same goes to Type B.

Comment: We're not getting anywhere. You should amend your question to describe *exactly* how you decide to classify any given instance of leave as one type or the other. No-one can give you words for something if you don't explain what that "something" is. Not every employer makes the same kinds of distinctions between different types of leave.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you may refer to this link - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46215/applying-earning-validating-leave for more details. In the link, there are many helpful people who suggest two or more wordings. However, what I would like is to have 1 word to describe. Hope that will make it simple to understand.

Comment: From these comments, there's clearly scope for confusion so I wouldn't advise reducing the terms to single words, which max only further increase confusion. One word doesn't always or automatically make things simpler. If there's not enough room on the form for two short words, I suggest redesigning the form.

Comment: Thanks Hugo, I still I need more time to persuade the user to forget using single word. I personally feel that 'Leave Credit' and 'Request Leave' is already sufficient. Please put your comments as answer so that I can close this question. Thanks.

Comment: If the user will understand from context that leave is being discussed, might words like "Added" or "Credited" or "Earned" work for the first type, and "Requested" work for the second?

Comment: Yes, I do hope that the user understand but as I have describe in my question, single word like 'Credit' for first type and 'Request' for second type to the user, they still feel "ambiguous".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "too localised". In passing, I think it's a bit silly that I have to ask several times what exactly OP means by these two types of leave, only to eventually be given a link to OP's question from last week asking about exactly the same thing. ELU is not a UI design service!

Comment: It seems like he wants to know the difference between "paid" and "unpaid" leave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question comments, there's clearly scope for confusion so I wouldn't advise reducing the terms to single words, which may only further increase confusion.

One word doesn't always or automatically make things simpler. If there's not enough room on the form for two short words, I suggest redesigning the form.